# Statistical test to compare two logistic curves

Tags: nonlinear-regression, biostatistics

I monitored relative humidity (y) produced from two groups of insects over time (x). I took readings from both groups 4 times each, giving me two curves of the mean humidity output from each group and I'd like to compare them. I am wondering if there is a simple statistical test that I can report showing that there is no evidence of a difference between the curves. Graphically, it appears obvious that these curves are nearly identical. But I would like to report some sort of statistical test if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: I might argue that if the subject matter expert judges the observed differences to be trivial, it doesn’t matter if there is any statistical significance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Canonical Correlation Analysis ([CCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation#Hypothesis_testing)) - it's a superset of all the parametric tests of significance.
Alternatively, this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics) of non-parametric tests with descriptions will most likely lead you in the right direction.